# JBoss EAP 6.4 to WildFly 10 application migration issue

Tags: java, jboss

I have a web application that loads cxf interceptors using jbossws-cxf.xml file and It's working fine on JBoss EAP 6.4
I'm trying to migrate the app to JBoss WildFly 10 but that file is being ignored by the server so the interceptors aren't loaded when the app starts.
What should I do for make it works?

Notes: The web.xml and jboss-web.xml files do not contain information about cxf or spring classes.

Comment: I'd suggest you to take a look at [WildFly 10 CXF Integration docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Apache+CXF+integration), [JBoss Advanced User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/Advanced+User+Guide#AdvancedUserGuide-ApacheCXFapproach) and to [this tutorial](http://www.radcortez.com/wildfly-apache-cxf-and-schemavalidation/).

Comment: Hey aribeiro! Thanks for the links. I could make it works using the JBoss way for using cxf without spring described in the JBoss Advanced User Guide you recommended.

Comment: I think this is the best way to use cxf with JBoss libraries.
Thanks for comment.

Comment: Check the automated pluggable rule-based migration tool [JBoss Windup](http://windup.jboss.org). EAP 6 to EAP 7 rules are being created.